# How to store Log File data on Hyperledger Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I want to store Log file data on the private blockchain Hyperledger fabric.
Please tell me is it possible?
If yes, the what steps I need to follow? and what are the steps?

To store Log data Line by line on Hyperledger fabric

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to store log file data on the Hyperledger Fabric. Here is the general overview:

1. Create a channel on the Blockchain
2. Write chaincode to store the log file data
3. Install chaincode on all of the nodes in the channel
4. Initialize the chaincode
5. Invoke the chaincode to store the log file data.